# ImageMagick dll and Exe returns two different values for RMSE image comparison

Tags: c#, imagemagick, image-comparison

I'm using ImageMagick with version 7.0 installed in my machine. For RMSE comparison for the below CLI input i'm getting some values which are different when i use dll in my c# code.

CLI code:

```
magick.exe compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search "image1.jpg" "image2.jpg" null:
```

C# code:

```
double diff = image1.Compare(image2, ErrorMetric.RootMeanSquared);
```

Is anyone know how to get the same results?

Comment: That may not be a fair comparison. The first seems to do a sub image-search. I do not see any flag in the second to do the same, so I suspect that it is not searching across the whole image. I could be wrong, since I do not know C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Magick.NET code is different from what you want to do on the command line. That command would translated to this instead:

```
var searchResult = image1.SubImageSearch(image2, ErrorMetric.RootMeanSquared);
var diff = searchResult.SimilarityMetric;
```

Comment: Hi dlemstra, im using this call in one of my services. my image1 is an hd image and image 2 is very small area. While calling this method, its taking more than 1 min to return. How can I stop the execution after 30 sec ?